# Can I integrate Search Engine (solr search or lucene search) into Maximo?

Tags: solr, lucene, maximo

I are building addon on Maximo (Enterprise Asset Management Solution - IBM).
The addon can search on very large data (~ 50 million records) and full-text search.
So, What solution to do?

Thanks all so much!

Answer (score 1):

I built a similar Maximo add-on before. In our case, we have tables with 35-40 million records running on Oracle database. We use normal DB index and data retrieval is not fast but acceptable. Query joining two of such table generally return results in 10-15 seconds.